# Error when importing pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

When I try to import `pyplot` :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I get this error:

```
  File "/home/riless/script.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 109, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5agg.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .backend_qt5 import QtCore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 31, in <module>
    from .qt_compat import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, _getSaveFileName, __version__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/qt_compat.py", line 111, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name QtGui
```

I don't know if it may help, but:

- I've already installed Qt5 which I use with PySide.
- When I've compiled `PyQt gpl 5.4.1` I've set the option `--qmake` with the path to the qmake binary included with Qt5 that I have.
- I've installed matplotlib with `pip install matplotlib`

**Edit:**

- Notice that the `QtCore` seems to be well imported but there is a problem avec `QtGui`

Comment: The PyQt5 you compiled probably got installed to the wrong location. Are you sure you configured it using the same python as the one used by matplotlib (i.e. `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`)?

Comment: yes, the PyQt5 installation is well configured

Comment: Well, obviously it isn't, otherwise you'd be able to import it. Don't make assumptions: check where it actually got installed.

Comment: I've made an edit, it means normally that PyQt5 is well installed, doesn't it ?

Comment: See my previous comment...